# Яндекс.Танк передача видеоданных

Tags: аудио, видео, яндекс-танк

Может ли быть танк полезем при нагрузочном тестировании приложения типа «Видеоконференция» обеспечивающее клиентам  передачу потоковых аудиоданных и видеоданных в режиме реального времени?

Comment: а что вы подразумеваете под словом `танк`?

Comment: @АлексейОсецкий Я там правильную меточку добавил к вопросу ...  Под танком обычно понимают яндекс-танк, инструмент нагрузочного тестирования

Answer (score 0):

Придется написать на go для генератора нагрузки pandora реализацию клиента к вашему сервису https://yandexpandora.readthedocs.io/en/develop/
и затем использовать связку yandex-tank + pandora https://yandextank.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core_and_modules.html#pandora

---

pandora мы активно используем для не http/https тестов, т.е там где phantom непригоден, и нужна высокая производительность в отличие от BFG. Сравнительные тесты с phantom-ом были опубликованы тут - https://github.com/yandex/pandora/blob/develop/docs/performance.rst